# WebGL batching: reducing the number of transforms I need to send

Tags: javascript, html, glsl, webgl

I am currently drawing objects in a single draw call. Each object is just a bunch of vertices with one transform, one color, and a stream of vertices:

```
uniform vec4 color;
uniform mat4 transform;
attribute vec3 vertex;
```

I would like to batch multiple objects into a single draw call, but I can't figure out how to send the color and transform. Should I just turn them both into per-vertex attributes, which would lead to sending a lot of duplicate data. Is there some way that I can send all the colors and transforms to an array on the gpu, and then just pass a color index and transform index with each vertex so that it can retrieve the appropriate color and transform for that vertex?

Or is there some other, hopefully much more elegant solution that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Just make your uniforms arrays and add an index attribute:

```
uniform vec4 color[MAX_OBJECTS];
uniform mat4 transform[MAX_OBJECTS];
attribute vec3 vertex;
attribute float index;
```

Where `MAX_OBJECTS` is appropriately defined for your platform. If your platform has limited uniform space (e.g. mobile gpu) you might want to store the colours in the vertex buffer.

Comment: Will there be a significant penalty for indirecting through an array? I'm using WebGL + latest Chrome on a relatively new laptop that has 1GB of GPU RAM. Are there any other scenarios in which I would want to store the colors (or transforms, if that's possible) in the vertex buffer?

Comment: I wouldn't expect a big penalty from the indirection, although it's impossible to say for sure without testing. Whether it makes sense to store the colours in the vertex buffer depends on whether they change from frame to frame and whether they are uniform for each object. I don't think it would ever make sense to store the transforms in the buffer. You might as well then just store the transformed vertex position.

Comment: By the way - I have used exactly this technique before. It did provide a good performance benefit, but it was quite a long time ago using DirectX where there was a big per-batch cost. I don't know whether these days (and using OpenGL) it will make so much difference. As ever, the only way to be sure is to test.

Comment: I've heard anecdotally that draw calls are expensive in WebGL, since there's an additional message passing interface that must be crossed. (Chrome's WebGL implementation has a client and server architecture that communicates through a token buffer.) So I figured that I would try that first to improve performance. I'll report with some numbers.